# How to distinguish whether a page is published first time or multiple times in publish environment of Adobe CQ5

Tags: aem

I need to display labels "New" and "Updated" besides the links displayed on a page on my website.

For this I applied a logic of checking number of versions. If number of versions are more than 2 I displayed "updated" else i displayed "New". I am able to achieve it in the Author environment.

But in Publish environment, number of versions created for a page, even though the page is modified and republished, are one only. So how can i identify that whether the page is published first time or it has been published multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion to this is to implement you own servlet/listener that listens to the replication events. Look at the EventHandler and JobProcessor interfaces. This servlet could then for example set a property value on the component instance so that the component could be displayed different the first time. It could just be a small counter variable that keeps track of how many times the actualy thing has been published or some more fancy logic there :)

```
//imports

@Service...
@Component...
@Property(name = "event.topics", value = ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC)
public class MyCustomEventHandler implements EventHandler, JobProcessor {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCustomEventHandler.class);

@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    LOGGER.info("Handling an event of some kind !!");
    process (event);
}

@Override
public boolean process(Event event) {
    LOGGER.info("Processing an event !!");
    ReplicationAction action = ReplicationAction.fromEvent(event);
    if (action.getType().equals(ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE)) {
        LOGGER.info("Processing an activation job, this is just what we are looking for !!!!!");

            //Logic for fetching/setting the properties you want from the component you want
            //goes here. Here you can make use of the action.getPath(); to get hold of the containing page
            //and then later on any specific components...
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

To see my original answer head over to: http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__kbyb-i_need_to_displayla.html